# MySQL - Like multiple parts of a string

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible in MySQL to do a 'like' in the statement that matches any part of a string.

It's hard to explain but I can give an example.

I am concatenating two columns together to display a full name (e.g John Barry Smith) the first name is 'John Barry' the last name is 'Smith'

I am making a filter and I would like it where I can type in 'John Smith' , which will then be passed through as the 'like' (or something similar) in the where clause and it will bring up the user rather than having to type 'John Barry' as not all of the users in the table have a middle.

Hopefully i've been clear enough in my question.

Comment: I suggest actually maintaining separate columns for the first, middle, and last name components.  That failing, if you must do it this way, consider reading about full text search in MySQL.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately in this case, i'm unable to make that change to the database. I will look into the MySQL full text search though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

`WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE ('john%smith')`

To list all "John sth sth Smith"s

Or even `LIKE ('%john%smith%')` to list al "sth sth John sth sth Smith sth"s (just replace all spaces with %'s)

An other option would be to split your search on spaces and do a LIKE for each word to list al Johns, and all Smiths, but this would be irrelevant I think.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped a lot. Unfortunately for me in the codeigniter project i'm using, I can't get it to do this. I pass through a query and the where clause is 'Like ?' and then it converts to '%?%'. Sadly for me if i enter multiple words, it does not add the extra wildcard in.

Comment: You could try to replace the spaces in your variable with %'s before preparing your statement so that you like pass the following value "$queryValue = 'john%smith'; Not sure how Codeigniter handles/escapes/strips %'s in strings when preparing the statement.

Comment: Yeah because the search/select2 will contain spaces between the names, i'm just going to explode on space and build a string with the wildcards. Thank you so much for the help! 